# Adding interface with existing method signature that is annotated with JPA breaks Eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

For a long time, I had the following classes with persistence use JPA and Eclipselink as persistence provider, which were persisted and queried sucessfully.

ProductKeyImpl:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_KEY")
@Access(PROPERTY)
public class ProductKeyImpl implements ProductKey {
    ...
}
```

derived class SomeProductKeyImpl:

```
@Entity
public class SomeProductKeyImpl
    extends ProductKeyImpl
    implements SomeProductKey {
    private String accoStockCode = null;
    ....
    @Column(name = "KEY_3")
    public String getAccoStockCode() {
        return this.accoStockCode;
    }
}
```

implementing the interface SomeProductKey:

```
public interface SomeProductKey extends ProductKey {
    String getAccoStockCode();
}
```

During a refactoring the method `getAccoStockCode()` was moved to a new interface `HasAccoStockCode` which is implemented by `SomeProductKey`:

```
public interface HasAccoStockCode {
    String getAccoStockCode();
}
```

and

```
public interface SomeProductKey extends ProductKey, HasAccoStockCode {
    // getAccoStockCode() removed
}
```

Since this change, queries are failing, because apparently Eclipselink does not only add the annotated mapping for accoStockCode to KEY_3 to the SQL, but a default mapping for the getAccoStockCode method from the HasAccoStockCode as well:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "ACCOSTOCKCODE": ungültiger Bezeichner

Error Code: 904
Call: SELECT ..., ACCOSTOCKCODE, KEY_3 ... FROM PRODUCT_KEY WHERE (ID = ?)
```

The correct select statement should not include ACCOSTOCKCODE, because the property is mapped to KEY_3

I see the same behaviour with Eclipselink 2.4.2 as well. In case it matters, the code is running on Weblogic 12.1.2 on Java 7.

Any ideas what I can do besides reverting the refactoring?

Edit after @Chris question:
If I remove getAccoStockCode() from the interfaces, the same error still occurs (unexpectedly to me...). 
You're question lead me to another testcase. The JPQL

```
SELECT a FROM SomeProductKeyImpl a WHERE a.oid = :id
```

is executed just fine with the SQL

```
SELECT ID, PRODUCT_KEY_SUBCLASS_CODE, TIME_STAMP, KEY_3, KEY_4, KEY_2, KEY_1 FROM VRPBOOKING.PRODUCT_KEY WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (PRODUCT_KEY_SUBCLASS_CODE = ?))
bind => [123, SPK]
```

If I query the superclass with the JPQL

```
SELECT a FROM ProductKeyImpl a WHERE a.oid = :id
```

the generated SQL is

```
SELECT ID, PRODUCT_KEY_SUBCLASS_CODE, TIME_STAMP, KEY_1, KEY_2, KEY_3, KEY_4, KEY_5, KEY_6, KEY_7, KEY_8, KEY_9, ACCOSTOCKCODE FROM VRPBOOKING.PRODUCT_KEY WHERE (ID = ?)
bind => [123]
```

and fails.

Comment: Just for clarification, does this work if you remove the getAccoStockCode() method from all the interfaces?  What is generated if you execute a query using the accoStockCode within the JPQL?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was actually not an Eclipselink problem, but a developer problem. We have another class SomeOtherProductKeyImpl that was changed to implement the interface, but did not have an annotation for getAccoStockCode(). Once it was annotated, everything worked fine.
Thanks again to @Chris for asking the questions that lead to the solution.